# Providing a generic key comparison based on a collection of a generic type

Tags: c#, linq, generics, expression-trees, func

I have created my own `InsertOrUpdate()` implementations for a few types like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Genre> InsertOrUpdate(IEnumerable<Genre> genres)
{
    foreach (var genre in genres)
    {
        var existingGenre = _context.Genres.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TmdbId == genre.TmdbId);
        if (existingGenre != null)
        {
            existingGenre.Update(genre);
            yield return existingGenre;
        }
        else
        {
            _context.Genres.Add(genre);
            yield return genre;
        }
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The return type of `IEnumerable<T>` is required because it will be used to insert the root object in the datacontext. This method basically retrieves the attached object if it exists and updates it with the newest values if it does or inserts it as a new object if it doesn't. Afterwards this attached object is returned so it can be linked to the root object in the many-to-many tables.

The problem now is that I have several of these collections (genres, posters, keywords, etc) and each type's ID is differently setup: sometimes it's called `TmdbId`, sometimes `Id` and sometimes `Iso`. It's one thing to use an interface and rename them all to `Id` but the problem exists in that they are also different types: some are `int` and some are `string`.

The question is easy: how I do turn this into something more generic to avoid this code duplication?

So far I have been toying around with

```
public IEnumerable<T> InsertOrUpdate<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities, Func<T, bool> idExpression) where T : class 
{
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var existingEntity = _context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefault(idExpression);
        if (existingEntity != null)
        {
            _context.Entry(existingEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
            yield return existingEntity;
        }
        else
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            yield return entity;
        }
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

but obviously this won't work since I have no access to the inner `entity` variable. Sidenote: `IDbSet<T>().AddOrUpdate()` [does not work in my scenario](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2128).

Comment: What do you mean with `I have no access to the inner entity variable`? `entity` is the variable of the `foreach`

Comment: @xanatos: I mean from the perspective of the caller. Ideally I would be able to pass something like `x => x.TmdbId == entity.TmdbId` as an argument to specify what should be compared, but I can't do that since I don't have access to entity from that context.

Comment: Mmmh... So how can you call `InsertOrUpdate` if you don't know the type of T? (note that instead of `Func<T, bool>` you should use `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`). If you show us how you call `InsertOrUpdate` it will become clearer

Comment: It is currently used as such: `movie.Genres = new List<Genre>(InsertOrUpdate(movie.Genres));` and likewise for all other collections. I realize that I might be trying to do something that isn't possible so I'm looking for the best way to approach a problem like this. As to your sidenote: do you have any literature handy where I can read up on that?

Comment: No :-) I don't read books... My attention span is too much short sadly :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
public IEnumerable<T> InsertOrUpdate<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities, Func<T, object[]> idExpression) where T : class
```

and

```
var existingEntity = _context.Set<T>().Find(idExpression(entity));
```

called with something like

```
movie.Genres = new List<Genre>(InsertOrUpdate(movie.Genres, x => new object[] { x.Id }));
```

(note that a method that returns a `IEnumerable<>` is **very** dangerous... If you don't enumerate it, like

```
InsertOrUpdate(movie.Genres, x => x.Id);
```

then the method won't be executed fully, because it will be lazily executed "on demand")

If you only have single-key tables, you can change it to:

```
public IEnumerable<T> InsertOrUpdate<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities, Func<T, object> idExpression) where T : class
```

and

```
var existingEntity = _context.Set<T>().Find(new object[] { idExpression(entity) });
```

and

```
movie.Genres = new List<Genre>(InsertOrUpdate(movie.Genres, x => x.Id));
```

Comment: This looks like what I want to do but I'm receiving an ArgumentException: **The specified parameter type 'System.Func\`2[[Models.Movies.Genre, Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not valid. Only scalar types, such as System.Int32, System.Decimal, System.DateTime, and System.Guid, are supported.**. Note that this remains even after adding a generic `TKey` type parameter instead of passing it as `object`. Any clue?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Are you sure you copied the Find correctly? It seems you are passing the `delegate` instead of calling it! Try putting the result of idExpression(...) in a temp variable (it is teh same error I got the first time I tried the code :-) )

Comment: Looking at the error, you are using a `Func<Genre, int>`. It is wrong. It should be a `Func<Genre, object[]>` or `Func<Genre, object>` depending on which variant you use

Comment: You're right, I totally read past that! It works perfectly. I didn't notice the `idExpression(entity)` instead of just `idExpression`. Looks like I have a lot to read up on regarding expressions.

Comment: The `Func<Genre, int>` is allowed because it is boxed into a `params object[]` by the `Find()` call anyway. Right now I'm using it as another type parameter instead of passing `object`.