# how to Find a generic-type entity object without knowing its key values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code to check if a generic type entity object is in context or database and if not, add it to the database:

```
public bool Post(T TObject)
    {
        if (context.Set<T>().Find(TObject) == null)
        {                
            context.Set<T>().Add(TObject); 
            context.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

It is not working because i'm using "Find" method with and object and not with a key value, i did that because i can´t know the TObject's key value, since it is a of generic type.

My question is, how could i implement it to first check if TObject is in context or in database and if not, add it to the database.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Providing a generic key comparison based on a collection of a generic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063445/providing-a-generic-key-comparison-based-on-a-collection-of-a-generic-type)

Comment: Do you have some base type for all entities with `Id` property?